# I want to compare the equality of dates in one column, which is placed in one table

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi before start explaining you my problem, first of all i want to say that search multiple times in google for this problem and yet i could not fine good answers.
My task is to find dates which is the equal of another date in the same column

I tried this:

```
select text, text as text1, date, date as 1
from task
where Date = Date1;
```

It occured an error: Date1 invalid ID

**Data:**

```
Text     | Date
---------+-----------
Sample1  | 2018 1 23
Sample2  | 2018 1 15
Sample3  | 2018 4 26
Sample4  | 2018 1 23
```

**Output:**

```
Text     | Text1
---------+--------
Sample1  | Sample2
```

Comment: some sample input output required what do you mean by in same column?

Comment: sample 1 and sample 4 should b the output as their dates matches is not it??

Comment: Yes you are right @nikhilsugandh the output is sample 1 and sample 2 because the dates matches

Comment: the ouput will be sample 1 and sample 4 their dates matches??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
T1.Text as Text, 
T2.Text as Text1
from Task T1 
inner Join Taks T2 on T1.Date = T2.Date
```

Comment: Thank you, new to this and still searching for the right functions and stuff like that.

Comment: its showing 6 rows  i dont know why is it accepted even

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
  create table table301(col1 varchar(20),col2 date);


insert into table301 values('Sample1' ,  '23-jan-2018');
insert into table301 values('Sample2' ,  '15-jan-2018' );
insert into table301 values('Sample3' ,  '26-apr-2018');
insert into table301 values('Sample4' ,  '23-jan-018');

SELECT * FROM table301;
SELECT a.col1,b.col1 FROM table301 a ,table301 b where sysdate- 
a.col2=sysdate-b.col2 and a.col1<>b.col1 and rownum<=1;
```

output:

```
Sample4 Sample1
```